# Writing on serial port COM1 in a kernel from scratch

Tags: c, serial-port, kernel, i386

I'm writing an i386 ELF kernel from scratch. I need to be able to write to the serial port COM1.

I have wrote two functions, `serial_init()` is called every time I call `printk(char* str)` which calls for each iteration for each character `serial_putc(char c)`.

```
#define SERIAL_COM1 (0x03f8)

void serial_putc(char c)
{
    char* serial = (char*)SERIAL_COM1;

    while ((serial[5] & 0x20) == 0);
    serial[0] = c;
}

void serial_init()
{
    char* serial = (char*)SERIAL_COM1;

    serial[1] = 0x00;
    serial[3] = 0x80;
    serial[0] = 0x03;
    serial[1] = 0x00;
    serial[3] = 0x03;
    serial[2] = 0xc7;
    serial[4] = 0x0b;
}
```

The line protocol is:

- 38400 bauds
- 8 bits per word
- No parity check
- 1 stop bit

I'm using `qemu-system-i386 -serial stdio -kernel ./kernel` to test my kernel but it doesn't print anything on the output on the serial port.

Since I needed to write `outb` and `inb` here is the code:

```
inline void outb(unsigned int port, unsigned char val)
{
    asm volatile ("outb %%al,%%dx": :"d" (port), "a" (val));
}

inline unsigned char inb(unsigned int port)
{
    unsigned char ret;

    asm volatile ("inb %%dx,%%al":"=a" (ret):"d" (port));
    return (ret);
}
```

I still can't get an ouput.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what tool do you use for compiling ? is your gcc compiled for crosscompil ?

Comment: It's the gcc from Debian 8 so I don't know. How can I find out and is it related to my issue about writing on the serial port (just curious) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at outb() and inb(), you can't write on your COM1 address like that.

Comment: Isn't `outb()` and `inb()` just macros of what I'm doing ? When trying to use `outb()` or `inb()` I can't compile since I don't have the header file `compat/deprecated.h`.

Comment: I have edited my post to add the `outb` and `inb` function I have wrote.